# How do I make List 1 based rather than 0 based

Tags: apex, list, pagination

EDIT:

```
public class ProductWrapper {

    public Product2 product {get;set;}
    public asset_line_items__c ali {get;set;}    

    public ProductWrapper(Product2 p, asset_line_items__c ali) {
        product = p;
        this.ali = ali;
    }
}
```

END:

Is there a way to start List index based on 1 rather than 0 ?

I'm having issue with pagination setPageSize, I'm loading the data off of custom wrapper through List.

when the very first page loads it add extra row, meaning that, if I setPageSize = 5 I expect to see 5 rows correct but I see 6 rows and when I click the next button I see 5 rows.

After looking through my code I realize that since I'm using the List and List index starts with 0.

What will be the alternate solutions to this problem?
Is that best practice to use List in the pagination scenarios?

```
public List<ProductWrapper> Products 
     {
      get 
      {
         List<Product2> products2 = new List<Product2>(); 
         list<ProductWrapper> pws = new list<ProductWrapper>();                 
         for(Product2 p : (List<Product2>)standardSetCtrl.getRecords()) {  
           if(p.Asset_Line_items__r.isEmpty()){
               pws.add(New ProductWrapper(p,New Asset_Line_Item__c(Quantity__c = 0));
               continue;
           }
        for(asset_line_items__c b : p.asset_line_items__r) { 
            ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper((Product2)p,b);
            pws.add(pw);
         }
     }    
  Products2 = pws;
  return Products2;
 }
 set;
}
```

My standardSetController:

```
 Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
    Public Integer size{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetCtrl {
        get{
            if(standardSetCtrl == null){
                size = 5;
                string queryString = 'Select Name....';
                standardSetCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
                standardSetCtrl.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = standardSetCtrl.getResultSize();
            }
            return standardSetCtrl;
        }set;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, as written, wouldn't compile. You're trying to assign a `List<ProductWrapper>` to a `List<Product2>`. From what I can deduce, you're actually adding *one line item per asset line item*, which means that one of your products probably had two line items. It's kind of hard to tell exactly, because of your compilation problems. The problem definitely is not the fact that lists are zero-based. In fact, to prove I'm not crazy, I wrote some code:

```
public class AccountPagination {
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController c { get; set; }
    public AccountPagination() {
        c = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name FROM Account]));
        c.setPageSize(5);
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="AccountPagination">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!0}" />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.first}" value="First" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.previous}" value="Prev" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.next}" value="Next" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.last}" value="Last" />
                {!c.pageNumber} of {!(c.resultSize+c.pageSize-1)/c.pageSize}
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!c.records}" var="acct">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!counter+1}" />
                    {!counter}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!acct['Name']}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You can try this out in your org, too, and you'll see what proper pagination *should* look like. You simply have a logic bug in your code elsewhere.

---

Edit: added a wrapper as an example:

```
public class AccountPagination {
    public class AccountWrapper {
        public Account record { get; set; }
        public AccountWrapper(Account record) {
            this.record = record;
        }
    }
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController c { get; set; }
    public AccountPagination() {
        c = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name FROM Account]));
        c.setPageSize(5);
    }
    public AccountWrapper[] getWrapperList() {
        AccountWrapper[] results = new AccountWrapper[0];
        for(Account record:(Account[])c.getRecords()) {
            results.add(new AccountWrapper(record));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="AccountPagination">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!0}" />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.first}" value="First" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.previous}" value="Prev" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.next}" value="Next" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!c.last}" value="Last" />
                {!c.pageNumber} of {!(c.resultSize+c.pageSize-1)/c.pageSize}
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="acct">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!counter+1}" />
                    {!counter}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!acct.record.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: yes if you use any standard object or custom object that works but have yo u tried using any wrapper class and load the data into the List? as you can see I'm using the `List<ProductWrapper>` I will update you the wrapper code in a sec.

Comment: I have updated my question with wrapper class to give you clear picture.

Comment: @NickKahn Adding a wrapper to my code didn't change the result: it still works as expected. See my edit.

Comment: the one thing i see the difference is `[]` vs. `List`, I'm using List oppose to `[]`

Comment: @NickKahn That's syntactic sugar. They mean the same thing as far as the compiler's concerned, but I have an aversion to typing `List<>` instead of just `[]`. I did change it in my developer org, and as expected, it still works correctly. I don't deny you're having a problem somewhere, but it's not the code you think it is. The StandardSetController is reliable for pagination without any special "tricks."

Comment: I have tried doing something like this: standardSetCtrl.setPageSize(5-1); then it displays `5 rows` when the page loads correct but when I click on next() then it displays 4 rows. the only conclusion i have is the List being a culprit but since you telling me the list is not then I'm clueless now

Comment: @NickKahn Try commenting out the entire `if` block in your code. I think that's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: yaaaaa worked you know that culprit was? `continue` I just realized that I somehow deleted the line when I was formatting the question so there was a line in the first `for loop` that says `continue` and I will update the question to be look complete.

Comment: @NickKahn You're welcome! Sometimes it's just the smallest thing that trips us up. Happens to the best of us. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Oops I was little excited but it works for edit page but if I'm creating a new record then its still show me 6 rows but this time at least i know what causing, how would you retrofit this line `pws.add(New ProductWrapper(p,New Asset_Line_Item__c(Quantity__c = 0));` this is adding an extra line which is not coming from `standardSetCtrl` and thats why i see extra row

Comment: I'm thinking i should also add the row into the `standardSetCtrl` to do proper pagination?

Comment: @NickKahn You can paginate over any sobject list, so you could indeed clone the results of a query, insert a new "blank" row at the beginning, and then use that list in your controller.

Comment: if you want i can create a new question, its up to you!  but can you show me how you thinking writing code?

Comment: @NickKahn I think I'd be concerned about view state size at that point, though, thinking about it. I think you might want to consider a different approach to your UI entirely. Perhaps another question is warranted, one with a screenshot, a description of what you're trying to do, and maybe some code of where you're stuck.

Comment: Its impossible to change the UI we are too far building the UI but I will post another question and let you know here. posted my question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141216/adding-a-new-row-into-standardsetcontroller